# Ratio of convergence

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $ \phi(z)= \log (1 + \sin z) $ for a small disk, (the origin is the center of the disk)
Find the ratio of convergence of Taylor series?

If we consider that $\log(1 +z) =  \sum_0^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n z^n}{n}$  where $|z|<1$ we found that  $\log(1 +\sin z) =  \sum_0^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n(\sin z)^n}{n}$  where $|\sin z|<1$ So the radius of convergence is where modulus of $\sin z$ is less than $1$?

Comment: Says what this criterion? @André Nicolas, and thanks for answering

Comment: _Radius_ of convergence?

Comment: one of the many absurdly nice features of holomorphic functions is not only that they are analytic in the sense that they may locally be represented by a power series, but indeed that this power series has radius of convergence at least as large as the distance from the center to the boundary of the region on which the function is holomorphic. My favorite example is 

$$\frac{1}{1 + x^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n x^{2n}$$

On the real line this is a smooth function, defined everywhere, and as the restriction of a holomorphic function is analytic,

Comment: yet for some reason the Taylor series at the origin has radius 1. Yet when we extend this function into the complex plane it is painfully obvious why this must be the case: there are poles at $\pm i$, distance 1 from the origin.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** For the radius of convergence, a useful criterion here is the "up to the first singularity" criterion.